# Insects coming from gap under baseboard radiator, seeking solution

Tags: heating, pest-control, caulking, laminate-floor

I have a ground-level apartment in Metro Detroit, Michigan and am renting.

I have old-style baseboard radiator heat with a large opening that goes across the length of it, as shown in the photo.

Also, there is a small gap between the laminate flooring and the wall, presumably for expansion.

As the temps are warming, I am getting spiders, ants, and possibly click beetles (can't confirm for sure if that's where they are coming from but fairly certain).

Landlord isn't helping, they insist on bug traps which don't work for me.

Last summer I covered it up with tape, but I want to avoid that this time.

Is it possible to caulk that gap between the laminate floor and wall? Does caulk give enough for expansion?

I am completely ignorant when it comes to this kind of stuff. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would a silicone caulking to seal the gap. Silicone caulk remains very flexible when it dries and will last for years.

Answer (score 0):

The floor under the heater is the same as the rest of the room, meaning  other than the opening for the pipe there is no gap for insect to enter. They are probably just seeking that space out because it is dark and warm.

They could be entering in a variety of places but the hole for the heating pipe is the most likely and the first to address, you could take some steel wool and stuff it into the gaps around the pipe. I do not think caulking the gap between the floor and the wall will accomplish anything and would be a messy difficult endeavor.

It is difficult to stop insects from getting into old homes and some are beneficial, coexist?